# How to create a duplicate custom record in netsuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I would like to know how can we create a Custom record from a existing custom record. My intention is to.

1. Rename the Custom Record
2. Copy a Custom record same structure to another one.

Do we have any option to write some script ? I found that some there is some "Down Load XML" option under the Action tab in every records type. It just create the structure of the record. But not sure how to use it.
TIA

Comment: do you have some code you could share?

Comment: I do not know what and how. I just see record on the browser.

Comment: Why do you want to have identical record types?

Comment: I want to copy the same record to another dev env. In my recent case one of my table got cashed and while reading the table its showing an old column name. So thought of recreating the same once again.

Answer (score 0):

Manually copying the custom record settings, fields, and forms will probably be faster than writing a script.  Depending on how many fields and forms you have, this could be done in 1-2 hours or less.

Comment: agree ... 
Do yo think "Down Load XML" can do some magic if I write a script. TIA

Comment: I would just manually copy, if I were you. It's really not that much work.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of copying tha custom record to another environment.
(1) You can bundle (using SuiteBundler)the custom record with or without data (Depending on your requirement) through this navigation Customization> suiteBundler> Create Bundle > List > New . Create new bundle and add the name and add the custom record of your choice. Share this bundle with the environment with which you want the bundle to install. Go to your new environment and seacrch and install this bundle. There is an option to persist data if you want to have the custom record moved along with data. However, the Ids of the columns should remain consistent across both the environments

(2) The next option is to manually create the structure of the new custom record in your new environment and  if you want the data to be same on the new custom record as the original one then download the csv file from your original custom record and do a CSV upload on the new one